# "Postfix" does not put fully qualified host name in the `From:` header line of an email sent using `mail` command

Tags: email, postfix, 23.04, 23.10

I have an old system lately upgraded from 23.04 to 23.10. However, **I do not know if this problem was present in the previous versions**, since I did not try to send emails in the previous versions.

My problem is that when I send an email from command line like this:

```
echo "Test content" | mail -s "Test subject" somebody@example.com
```

the `mail` command (or `postfix`) does not fill my fully qualified domain name in the `From:` line. This field contains only `me@host` as can be seen from the `mail.log` of the system and the email is rejected by the recipient.

When I use:

```
echo "Test content" | mail -s "Test subject" -r "me@host.mydomain" somebody@example.com
```

then the email is transferred correctly as expected.

My `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file contains:

```
myhostname = host.mydomain
mydestination = host.mydomain localhost.mydomain localhost
```

The `mail` command's version:

```
$ mail --version
mail (GNU Mailutils) 3.16
Copyright (C) 2007-2023 Free Software Foundation, inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Note that `mail` is a link to `/usr/bin/mail.mailutils` from:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/mail.mailutils
mailutils: /usr/bin/mail.mailutils
```

I have compared all these plus network configuration (hostname, dnsdomainname, DNS records, etc.) with another system which currently runs 23.04 and they are similar, but that system *does* act as expected by filling the fully qualified domain name in the `From:` line. So, I am hesitating to upgrade that system, in case that this problem is somehow related to binaries or default configurations provided in 23.10. :(

---

<sub>Obviously "host" and "mydomain" as given in the above examples are placeholders for the real names.</sub>

---